# Problems with animation in Firefox

Tags: html, jquery, css

There's a simple animation https://ektx.000webhostapp.com/firefox-animation/. Everything works fine in all browsers, but in Firefox, when pointing at a gray field, the circle twitches. Someone can tell me how to fix it so that the animation is smooth and in Firefox too.

```js
$('#section').on('mousemove', function(e) {
   let y = e.pageY - $(this).offset().top - ($(this).height()/2);
   let x = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left - ($(this).width()/2);
   x = x * 0.1; y = y * 0.1;
   $('.circle').css({ 'transform': 'translate( '+ x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)' });
});
```

```css
.section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  z-index: 1;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 45%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #2a3138;
  transition: 1.5s ease-out all;
}

.field {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #7d7f89;
}

.line {
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #2a3138;
  transition: 1.5s ease-out all;
}

.field:hover .line {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section" id="section">
  <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="field">
      <span class="line"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried with  this (-webkit-transition, -moz-transition, -o-transition) css properties?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't help.

Comment: have you checked if those functions are supported by firefox version you are using?

Comment: The code itself works normally, problems arise only when pointing at the gray field '.field', the figure twitches.

Comment: If you remove the transition from the '.line', then everything is fine. Or if the '.line' does not change size but color, for example, but transition leave, also works. But it is necessary that the size of the '.line' changes smoothly and the circle moves smoothly.